# Place the page title into the short code

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

I have created a short code called `[contianer-narrow][/container-narrow]` which wraps your content in a twitter bootstrap class: `.container-narrow` the issue is that the page title is not included. is there a way to say:

`if this short code is used, include the page title, else forget it?`

Comment: How are you using it?  Are you editing template files?  Could you post the full function that the short code calls?

Comment: As above, post your code please.

Comment: Are you wanting to switch the display of the title _inside_ the shortcode or somehow make the shortcode control the display of the title elsewhere in the page template? It sounds like the latter.

Answer (score 1):

As for your concrete question:
You *could theoretically* parse the retrieved content before shortcodes are resolved for this specific one, set a flag and wrap the title on condition of that.

But it would make much more sense to trash the shortcode-approach and simply [create a new page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).
(Especially so, given that the parsing for the shortcode, or at least its consequences, would have to happen in the used template file anyway)

Copy the contents of your theme's `page.php` to a new file.
Call that `page-narrow.php`.
Prepend it by

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Narrow Page
 */
?>
```

And wrap the copied part in an element with the desired class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this (not tested) :

```
function has_shortcode( $sc = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    foreach( $wp_query->posts as $post ) {
        if ( ! empty( $sc ) && stripos($post->post_content, '[' . $sc) !== false ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can use it like that :

```
if ( has_shortcode( 'container-narrow' ) {}
```